# Software to automate a phone call, send DTMF tones, and transcribe the responses

Tags: python, automation, phone, skype, transcription

I work at a radio station where we have to fill out transmitter logs. We get the values for the logs by making a phone call to an automated system (land-line phone). Here is the process I'm looking to automate:

1. Make a phone call to the transmitter's number
2. Wait for the automated system to answer
3. Dial the pass code and wait for a confirmation
4. Dial the channel number and transcribe the response into a text file
5. Repeat for all channels on each transmitter

I've looked at Skype4Py, but I'd prefer not to have to pay for the automation. I haven't looked at Twilio for the same reason. I'm also aware that Google has a beta of sorts for Google Voice, but that looks like it's specifically for the transcription services. Based on my experience with the voicemail transcription feature, the transcription itself would suffice for this. However, I don't think it's for placing phone calls. And as far as python libraries for Google Voice, I haven't found one that seems to be able to send dial tones.

Comment: OK, integrated that with your question. Next: does all communication happen via [DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling), or is it rather a "modem communication"? How does the "transcription" of the text file work?

Comment: Does it have to be in Python / does it have to work with Skype?

Comment: I'd prefer it didn't use Skype because outbound Skype calls cost money. And no, Python isn't necessary. It's just what I normally do automation in because it's what I'm most familiar with.And all communication from myself to the transmitter is done with DTMF. The responses are prerecorded audio of speech similar to automated phone menus for customer service. The transcription would be speech-to-text.

Answer (score 1):

For Python, you can use [PyAutoGUI](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/) (works on Windows, macOS, and Linux).

> A Python module for programmatically controlling the mouse and keyboard.

You can use [locate functions](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) to find specific buttons or objects within the screen in order to interact with them.

See also: [Python GUI automation library for simulating user interaction in apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42664/3474)